# Error using FuelSDK CSharp to create Email Send Definition

Tags: fuel-sdk

I am using the FuelSDK for Csharp and have hit a snag when attempting to PostReturn an EmailSendDefinition.  the error:

There was an error generating the XML document.

and if you dig further in, you see the inner exception providing a bit more light:

The type FuelSDK.ET_List was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

my code:

```
        int sendEmailId = 111111
        int toListId = 111111;
        ET_EmailSendDefinition sendReq = new ET_EmailSendDefinition();
        sendReq.AuthStub = myclient;
        sendReq.Name = "testsend1";
        sendReq.CustomerKey = "testsend1";
        sendReq.Description = "testing a send to subscribers of the list";
        sendReq.SendClassification = new ET_SendClassification() { CustomerKey = "xxx" }; 
        sendReq.SendDefinitionList = new ET_SendDefinitionList[] { 
        new ET_SendDefinitionList() { List = new ET_List() { ID = toListId }, 
        DataSourceTypeID = DataSourceTypeEnum.List } };
        sendReq.Email = new ET_Email() { ID = sendEmailId };
        PostReturn postESD = sendReq.Post();
```

Another post on this site deals exactly with this issue, with a solution of changing the List = new ET_List  to List = new FuelSDK.ET_List.  This doesn't work for me.  I have also tried various flavors of XmlSerialization declarations on the ET_List object in ET_Client.cs, with no luck.

My implementation of this is the FuelSDK is a seperate project in my solution and i have referenced that project from a testing project (console app).  i have not changed the namespace of FuelSDK.

Also, I have been able to successfully create a list and add subscribers to a list, so I am pretty sure the client object is functioning correctly.

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this.  Turns out that the "List" attribute of the ET_EmailSendDefinition.SendDefinitionList is actually an ET_AudienceItem object in the version of the SDK that I'm using.  The samples provided with the SDK indicated that it is an ET_List object.  Simply hovering over this attribute in the IDE revealed the problem.  the corrected code:

```
        AudienceItem ai = new AudienceItem();
        ai.List = new List { ID = toListId };
        sendReq.SendDefinitionList = new ET_SendDefinitionList[] { new ET_SendDefinitionList() { List = ai.List, DataSourceTypeID = DataSourceTypeEnum.List } };
```

hopefully, this will save someone down the road some time!

thanks!